# I am getting 404 when running MVC app in Visual Studio but friend is not

Tags: asp.net-mvc, git, visual-studio

I am developing a **C# MVP application** with a friend using git and visual studio. 
My friend made a few changes to how we handle errors and pushed that to git.

Now when I try to run our application (with GIT repo up to date) I get **404** on our only view not even hitting our controller, while on my friends PC and on our Azure service it is running fine.

Also tried on another friends PC and he also gets 404.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: It's pretty hard to answer this without seeing any code. Please read [ask].

Comment: Check the properties of your MVC project. Under the "Web" tab, take a look at the "Project Url" and verify that it is the Url you are opening (e.g. "http://localhost:8086/")

Comment: Chris as i stated in the question we have the same version of the code so i don't see this being a code question, hence i didn't see any code as relevant as i suspected this to be a Visual Studio configuration problem or similar. 
Thank you Georg i will look into that!

Answer (score 0):

Seems like i was missing the virtual directory.

went into properties for the project -> Web and clicked "Create Virtual Directory" and everything worked after that. Thank you leading me onto this Georg Patscheider.